# How to make upload handler in AppEngine for object uploaded to Google Cloud Storage with Blobstore API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

You can create an upload URL inside of Google App Engine using the Blobstore API like this:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String callbackUrl = "/imageApi/imageUploaded";
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(callbackUrl,
     UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("myBucket"));
```

But how do I then, inside of App Engine, create a Java method to handle the upload? What does it look like and how do I read in the object name of the file uploaded and what not?

I was looking at the blurb about it in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) but there really isn't any code there explaining how to do it.

Note: I am using cloud endpoints but it should be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a servlet that is mapped to your "/blob" handler. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Map<String, List<FileInfo>> files = blobstoreService.getFileInfos(request);
    List<FileInfo> info = files.get("uploadFormElement");

    for (FileInfo i : info) {
        if (i != null) {
            String objectName = i.getGsObjectName();
            long size = i.getSize());
            // if you want to return object name to the client:
            resp.getWriter().print(objectName);
        }
    }
}
```